# why does the top button still link to the top of the page?

Tags: html, document-body

I have a button `<a href="#top">Top</a>` linking to the top of the page `<body id="top"></body>`
but when removing the id of the body the button still works. I cant work this out, I put it down to the browser cacheing data although I have emptied the cache and re-tried and it still works. This is purely informative, its not causing me any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if the id does not exist, the browser will handle it the same as '#'. Which links to the start of the page.

Comment: So there is no use to giving the body tag an id then

Comment: @SamMarchant Well not really because the body tag is the top most element of the document. Unless there were margins added to the body. I would still encourage an id though as it is good readability.

Answer (score 1):

Unrecognised fragment identifiers are treated as being at the top of the document.

Comment: Ah so the page creates the link and immediately thinks its at the top of the page?